# GSL for Visual C++ 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, gsl

I'm trying to use the GSL 1.14 for VC2010 considering the build project proposed by Brian Glandman's (http://gladman.plushost.co.uk/oldsite/computing/gnu_scientific_library.php).
After building libraries I tried to run a simple example using the function gsl_sf_bessel_J0. See code below:

## include

## include

int main(){

```
double x;
double y;

do
{
    printf("\nInforme o valor de x: ");
    scanf_s("%lf", &x);
    y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (x);
    printf ("J0(%g) = %.18e\n", x, y);
} while (x!=0);
```

return 0;
}

The code compiles but the following messages appears. Even so the code properly calculates the function. I would like to know about these messages, mainly concerning with the possibility them generate some critical problems in most complicate codes.

'test_3.exe': Loaded 'C:\Documents and Settings\Francisco J. Profito\Meus documentos\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test_1\Debug\test_3.exe', Symbols loaded.
'test_3.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test_3.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test_3.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'test_3.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\shimeng.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'test_3.exe': Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\shimeng.dll'
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1644) has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The program '[5508] test_3.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).

1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: test_3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>cl : Command line warning D9007: '/Gm' requires '/Zi or /ZI'; option ignored
1>  test_3.cpp
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>  test_3.vcxproj -> C:\Documents and Settings\Francisco J. Profito\Meus documentos\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test_1\Debug\test_3.exe
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========